# ASP.NET Session difference InProc StateServer

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

[edit]
The real question is why

```
when EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" 

    sessionState mode="InProc" is not really readonly
    but sessionState mode="StateServer" is
```

[/edit]

I have an issue with session in my ASP.NET application.

Currently, on a webpage, I have a button to do a search (and save it in session), after the search is completed I have another button to do an action.
This action is called in a WebMethod, and I display an ajax progressbar.

When I developped this page, I had to set up the property EnableSessionState to "ReadOnly".

Even with this ReadOnly parameter, I am able to save the search in session.

Today I want to use StateServer mode for my session, but now, the session is realy in ReadOnly mode. So I can't get the result of my search to launch the action of the second button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Regards

Comment: Why did you have to set the property `EnableSessionState` to read only?

Comment: Access to ASP.NET session state is exclusive per session, which means that if two different users make concurrent requests, access to each separate session is granted concurrently. However, if two concurrent requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session information. The second request executes only after the first request is finished.
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, I have concluded this :

I set EnableSessionState to "ReadOnly", but in InProc mode I can still modify the session (with StateServer, session are **really** ReadOnly)
More info here :  http://forums.asp.net/t/7504.aspx?Understanding+session+state+modes+FAQ

In Asp.NET "if two concurrent requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session information. The second request executes only after the first request is finished."
So I can't launch 2 WebMethod (the progress bar, and the "business action") process together without setting ReadOnly parameter
More info here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

In my case I have a probleme because, I store the result of a search in session but now with StateServer my session's variable is ReadOnly so always empty

The solution that I have found is to use Cache and not Session for this webpage (but I can't explain in details all my workaround here)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the readonly setting and enable session state server in your web.config (system.web section):

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=server:port"></sessionState>
```

Comment: I have already setting session state in web.config. If I remove readonly, my ajax progress bar don't move, the http request is blocked